# How to normal distribute 1001 into 16 categories?

Tags: normal-distribution

I've the following problem given:

1001 entities
16 categories

I would like to distribute those 1001 entities into those 16 categories by normal distribution. I tried to use the excel function Normdist but were unable to understand how I need distribute it.

Am I even on the right path in using this function Normdist?

How would I do that using Normdist?

Comment: You mean something like the galton board ?

Comment: @callculus yes that would fit. A galton board.